# Giving 2D Array as Function Parameter and returning 2D Array as return type of the Function

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix

I am trying to find transpose of 2D Matrix and want to create a function 
that take my 2D array and number of values of Matrix as input and return the 
transpose of a 2D Matrix .
I have written the following code in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
 //int** transpose(int arr[][] , int n);
 int k=2;
 int ** transpose(int wt[1][k] , int n )
 {
    int trans[n][1];
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
         trans[i][1] = wt[1][i];
     }
     return trans ;
 }
 int main()
 {  int n;
 cin >> n;
 int wt_vect[1][n];
  for( int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
   wt_vect[1][i] = 0.7;
  }
int trans[n][1] = transpose(wt_vect , n);

     }
```

But getting error log as following

**7:30: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token
7:32: error: expected ')' before ',' token
7:34: error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'**

Please help me to find transpose using Function .
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449359/getting-error-array-bound-is-not-an-integer-constant-before-token

Comment: Please observe that `int wt_vect[1][n]` (where `n` is a variable) isn't (standard) C++.

Comment: And, please, observe that `wt_vect[1]` access to the **second** elemen; you should write `wt_vect[0][i]` if the first dimension of `wt_vect` is `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use C++, I suggest to avoid C-style array.

If you know run time the dimension, you can use `std::array`.

In your case (second dimension know run time) you can use `std::vector`.

The following is a full example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
using matrix = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;

template <typename T>
matrix<T> transpose (matrix<T> const & m0)
 {
   // detect the dim1 of m0
   auto dim1 = m0.size();

   // detect the dim2 of m0 (throw id dim1 is zero)
   auto dim2 = m0.at(0U).size();

   for ( auto const & r : m0 )
      if ( dim2 != r.size() )
         throw std::runtime_error("no consistent matrix");

   // new matrix with switched dimension
   matrix<T> ret(dim2, std::vector<T>(dim1));

   // transposition
   for ( auto i = 0U ; i < dim1 ; ++i )
      for ( auto j = 0U ; j < dim2 ; ++j )
         ret[j][i] = m0[i][j];

   return ret;
 }


int main ()
 {
   std::size_t n;

   std::cin >> n;

   matrix<int> mat(1U, std::vector<int>(n));

   for ( auto i = 0U ; i < n ; ++i )
      mat[0U][i] = 7;

   auto tam = transpose(mat);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically array sizes have to be known at compile time, basically it can't be a variable that could have any value, no value or changing value

Comment: then how do i fix the issue